# Analytics classic code: hitCallback

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I would like track a form post using analytics. from what I read I understand that I must use the 
[`hitCallback`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced) function otherwise the event tracker will not complete the tracking event.

The problem is that I am using the classic GA code (the newer version does not support 
re-marketing) which not support the `hitCallback` function.

Is there other way to do this?

Here is the code of what I am trying to do:

**Form submit:**

```
<input id="start1" type="submit" value="Send" onclick='return OnFormSubmit("1332","campaign: 12");' />

function OnFormSubmit(formIdentifier, label) {

  if (ValidateForm(formIdentifier)){
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Registration', 'form submited', label, , false]);
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

function ValidateForm(formIdentifier) {
  // validating the form inputs. 
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a mistake. The `hitCallback` function is working perfectly with the traditional GA code!

This following code is working - I can see the events on GA.

```
function OnFormSubmit(event, formIdentifier, formLabel) {

        event.preventDefault();

        if (ValidateForm(formIdentifier)) {

            $('#overlay').show();

            SendEmailToReferrer();

            //if analytics object exists
            if (window._gat) {
                optinForm = this;
                _gaq.push(['_set', 'hitCallback', function () {

                    SendForm();
                }]);

                _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Registration', 'Form submited', formLabel, , false]);
            }
            else {

                SendForm();
            }
        }
    }


function SendForm() {
        var serial = '@Model.SerialId';

        if (serial.val == "") { serial = '-1'; }

        var formURL = '@regFormURL';
        $('#frm1').attr('action', formURL + '?SerialId=' + serial);

        document.regForm1.submit();
    }
```